# MS ACCESS - SUM

Tags: ms-access

I have a form called Items list which stores multiple values for one project. i have a total for each item that is added (as seen in picture) i would now like to make it so that the "overall Total" field stores the overall total for the items for that project.... and then store it in a new field in the table.

[image]

Comment: Don't store computed values, except you get performance issues, because everytime you change `Rate`  or `Quantity` you have to update the computed value. Even `Total` should be computed `Sum(Quantity * Rate)`. Don't you need a `Discount` field?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(TOTAL) FROM TABLE
```

If necessary add the Total textbox value to above result, when any value(s) are edited in screen

Comment: I think you should add a `Group By` or a `Where` condtion for the projectid, as OP seems to be inexperienced in sql.